# Character value with embedded blanks with list input

Tags: sas

I would like to read following instream datalines

```
    datalines;
Smith,12,22,46,Green Hornets,AAA
FriedmanLi,23,19,25,High Volts,AAA
Jones,09,17,54,Las Vegas,AA
;
```

I employed while it read AAA items to team variables but not as div. And how should I place `&`(ampersand to read character with embedded blanks?)

```
data scores2;
    infile datalines dlm=",";
    input name : $10. score1-score3 team $20. div $;
    datalines;
Smith,12,22,46,Green Hornets,AAA
FriedmanLi,23,19,25,High Volts,AAA
Jones,09,17,54,Las Vegas,AA
;
run;
```

Comment: You meant to say that there are more than one blanks for the values in variable - team?

Comment: Only one blank. Like first observation that Green_Hornets . So there is blank for this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice I have used `:` before team also ( well you have already used colon operator `:` for other variables , not sure why did you miss over here) As I have already mentioned in your other query, use `:` colon operator ([tilde, dlm and colon format modifier in list input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793133/tilde-dlm-and-colon-format-modifier-in-list-input)) which would tell SAS to use the informat supplied but to stop reading the value for this variable when a delimiter is encountered. Here as you had not used this operator , that is why SAS was trying to read 20 chars, even though 
there was a delimiter in between.

**Tested**

```
data scores2;
    infile datalines dlm=",";
    input name : $10. 
          score1-score3 
          team : $20. 
          div : $3.;
datalines;
Smith,12,22,46,Green Hornets,AAA
FriedmanLi,23,19,25,High Volts,AAA
Jones,09,17,54,Las Vegas,AA
;
run;
```

Comment: ohh. careless mistake TT. Thanks for reminding. While interestingly i found another way to do the task is that i use dsd instead of dlm and ~ instead of :

Comment: That is the beauty of SAS, you can do the same thing in multiple ways.

Comment: Thanks NEOmen, sorry for one more question. What if the datalines do not contain delimiter ,? how can i produce same output?

Comment: There are multiple ways for doing so - but those have constraints - like if your data has fixed width then you specifically tell SAS like this - Subj $ 1-3 DOB $ 4-13 Gender $ 14 Balance 15-21;
Above query of yours has much broader perspective.

Comment: may u take above example if i replace all , to blank? Many many thanks

Comment: If you replace , with space here then i guess it would be impossible to read because of the variable - team as it contains blank spaces

Comment: In general either your provide delimiters or fixed width variables , otherwise SAS would not be able distinguish between start of one variable and end of another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68259/discussion-between-neomen-and-user).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this that's often a bit easier to read is to use the `informat` statement.

```
data scores2;
    infile datalines dlm=",";
    informat name $10.
             team $20.
             div $4.;
    input name $ score1-score3 team $ div $;
    datalines;
Smith,12,22,46,Green Hornets,AAA
FriedmanLi,23,19,25,High Volts,AAA
Jones,09,17,54,Las Vegas,AA
;
run;
```

That accomplishes the same thing as using the colon (`input name :$10.`) but organizes it a bit more cleanly.

And just to be clear, embedded blanks are irrelevant in comma delimited input; `'20'x` (ie, space) is just another character when it's not the delimiter.  What ampersand will do is addressed in [this article](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001360509.htm), and more specifically, if `space` is the delmiiter it allows you to require two consecutive delimiters to end a field.  Example:

```
data scores2;
    infile datalines dlm=" ";
    informat name $10.
             team $20.
             div $4.;
    input name $ score1-score3 team & $ div $;
    datalines;
Smith 12 22 46 Green Hornets  AAA
FriedmanLi 23 19 25 High Volts  AAA
Jones 09 17 54 Las Vegas  AA
;
run;
```

Note the double space after all of the team names - that's required by the `&`.  But this is only because delimiter is space (which is default, so if you removed the `dlm=' '` it would also be needed.)