# SAS: Reading fields from datalines in a data step

Tags: sas

Could someone please provide an explanation or a link which has explanation on the functionality of ':' in the below code:

```
data voter; 
infile datalines dsd dlm='~'
input age party : $1. (ques1 - Ques4) ($1. + 1); 

format age 2. party $1. ques1 - ques4 $likert.;
label Ques1 = ' performance '
        Ques2 = ' taxes '
        Ques3 = ' amenities '
        Ques4 = ' endurance ';
datalines;
23~D~2~1~3~4 
34~R~2~1~4~4 
43~D~2~2~1~1 
;
```

This is the test code used for learning SAS. When I remove the ':' from the INPUT statement I am not able to read the data properly. Also, kindly let me know what is the +1 in the ($1. + 1); context. This snippet is taken from learning SAS through examples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is called [colon operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793133/tilde-dlm-and-colon-format-modifier-in-list-input/27793506#27793506) which means - to stop reading when encounter a delimiter,
Because it is list input method, so point will move a unit forward

(Ques1-Ques4) ($1. +1);

is the same as  Ques1 $1. +1  Ques2 $1. +1   Ques3 $1. +1    Ques4 $1. +1 i.e. Increament +1 position for Ques2 from Ques1 and so on.

Comment: Can I use this increment technique while assigning the values in the datastep. e.g: something like (score1 - score10) = (subject1 - subject 10) (+1) ; I tried this, but getting error.

Comment: No you can't, while using this in infile statement you are using the positions to move through the variables but in a dataset you don't have positions as such.