# Invalid data for salary in line 3 1-8

Tags: sas

I have raw data in text file.

```
Hire Date empid Job Code Salary
17FEB1980 E00271 RESCLK $28,000
23FEB1980 E00166 MKTCLK $34,000
31MAR1980 E00151 MECH01 $41,000
28MAY1980 E00074 MECH03 $36,000
31MAY1980 E00222 PRES $250,000
05JUN1980 E00234 FINCLK $41,000
10JUL1980 E00350 FLTAT2 $19,000
```

I try to create the data set by the code.

```
data Test.mydataset;
infile rawdata  FirstObs=2;
Input Hire_data date9. empid$ Job_code $  Salary dollar8.;
run;
```

But I get a bunch of errors.

> Invalid data for salary in line 3 1-8
>   etc.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Lazy way to do this - use PROC import and code will be generated in the log. Take the code and customize as needed. For more help please post a larger portion of the log - it highlights the line and values at that point which is helpful for debugging.

Comment: Actual error is that SAS is going to line three when is sees there are only 7 characters left on line two and you told it to read 8 characters.  Adding TRUNCOVER will prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `dollar8.` as  the informat but your input feeds are of variable length,use [colon operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793133/tilde-dlm-and-colon-format-modifier-in-list-input)
to tell SAS to use the informat supplied but to stop reading the value for this variable when a delimiter is encountered. Do not forget the colons because without them SAS may read past a delimiter to satisfy the width specified in the informat, which is causing the issue in your case.

Solution:

```
data Test.mydataset;
infile rawdata  FirstObs=2;
Input Hire_data date9. empid$ Job_code $  Salary : dollar8.;
run;
```

Comment: When you say `variable length`, did you refer to `Job_code` column or `Salary` column in my case? Is `Job_code $` causing the issue? I have difficult time to understand `$`. Does it mean the field's length is less 8? So can I use `Job_code$7.` to deal with the issue?

Comment: its salary which is causing you the issue, because your data was less than 8 character in length. Its always advisable to use colon operator ,it would not do any harm to you, rather if your data is shorter than declared, it will stop reading right there at the delimiter

Comment: I am new to SAS. Sorry for my ignorance. Colon Operator is required to tell SAS to use the informat supplied but to stop reading the value for this variable when a delimiter is encountered. But in my case, Salary is the last column of a line. There is no delimiter after it, how can it encounter a delimiter?

Comment: SAS sees the carriage return and in case  of last column of line , it would stop right there

Answer (score 0):

The easiest change is to add the `TRUNCOVER` option to the `INFILE` statement to prevent SAS from going to a new line when the current line doesn't have enough characters.  You told it to read 8 characters but most of your SALARY values are only 7 characters long.

Best method is to define your variables using `ATTRIB` or `LENGTH` statement instead of letting SAS guess how to define them based on how you first reference them in the code. You can set the informat to use with an `INFORMAT` or `ATTRIB` statement.

```
data mytest ;
  infile cards truncover firstobs=2;
  length Hire_Date 8 Empid $10 Job_Code $10 Salary 8;
  informat Hire_Date date. Salary comma. ;
  format Hire_Date date9. Salary dollar8. ;
  input Hire_Date -- Salary ;
cards;
Hire Date empid Job Code Salary
17FEB1980 E00271 RESCLK $28,000
23FEB1980 E00166 MKTCLK $34,000
31MAR1980 E00151 MECH01 $41,000
28MAY1980 E00074 MECH03 $36,000
31MAY1980 E00222 PRES $250,000
05JUN1980 E00234 FINCLK $41,000
10JUL1980 E00350 FLTAT2 $19,000
;;;;
```